# Ubuntu Server, Exim4 and Spam Lists

Tags: server, email, mta

I have a Ubuntu Server with Exim4 MTA. Everything is running OK. I must integrate Spam Lists, in Exim4. How can I integrate Spam Lists with Exim4?

One of the Spam List i want to integrate is from Spamhaus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I just figured out, how it can work.

Edit the file:

```
vim /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options
```

Insert the following in bottom of the file:

```
# Spamhaus RBL zen.spamhaus.org
CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS = zen.spamhaus.org
```

Edit the file:

```
vim  /etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/30_exim4-config_check_rcpt
```

Search for:

```
CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
```

Then change, "warn" to "deny" as shown below:

```
# Check against classic DNS "black" lists (DNSBLs) which list
# sender IP addresses
.ifdef CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
deny
message = X-Warning: $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
log_message = $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
.endif
```

We must restart Exim:

```
/etc/init.d/exim4 restart
```

To test this configuration and see if the PBL blocking is working by sending an email (any email) to: nelson-pbl-test@crynwr.com

The system will answer, to tell if your server is correctly blocking PBL-listed IP addresses or not.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to show that it is the solution to future viewers of this question.

Comment: for other people seeing this, this won't work if you're using Google or some other open DNS on your server.  Essentially you'll find nothing gets blocked. http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#261